# Any suggestions as to how to export PDF with one set of data but two rows of headings?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, jspdf

I have a problem, up until now I have been using jspdf with autotable to create simple reports one row of headings, one body of data, works perfectly well.

I am using Angular 8

However I now have a report where I have this layout required:

```
Name: Steve    Age: 38    otherTitle: xxx    otherTitle: xxx   otherTitle: xxx
--NEWLINE--
otherTitle: xxx    otherTitle: xxx    otherTitle: xxx    otherTitle: xxx
```

essentially two lines of headers with the data to the right of them.

Layout on webpage is easy, works fine. but Exporting it to pdf I'm not sure how to do it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so im not exactly happy with my own solution but it kinda does what i want for now, if anyone else needs something similar, its not exactly going to win prizes..
If anyone has a better solution for creating pdfs using data like this then please reply ;D

*using jspdf still

thanks all.

```
const reportCreationDate = Date.now();
    let doc = new jsPDF('landscape') as jsPDFWithPlugin;
    doc.setFontSize(7);
    printArrayL1.forEach((el, i) => {
      doc.text(5, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[0]}`);
      doc.text(40, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[1]}`);
      doc.text(80, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[2]}`);
      doc.text(120, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[3]}`);
      doc.text(140, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[4]}`);
      doc.text(180, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[5]}`);
      doc.text(210, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[6]}`);
      doc.text(230, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[7]}`);
      doc.text(260, 10 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[8]}`);
    });
    printArrayL2.forEach((el, i) => {

      doc.text(5, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[0]}`);
      doc.text(40, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[1]}`);
      doc.text(80, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[2]}`);
      doc.text(120, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[3]}`);
      doc.text(140, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[4]}`);
      doc.text(180, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[5]}`);
      doc.text(210, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[6]}`);
      doc.text(230, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[7]}`);
      doc.text(260, 15 + (i * 10), `Header: ${el[8]}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps anyone but i had further issues when more than a page, here is how i managed to add a page and reset the position to the top for the next page.
essentially another index itemcount that gets reset. maybe it helps someone.

```
    let startY = 20;

    let itemcount = 0;
    printArray.forEach((el, i) => {
      itemcount++; 

      if (itemcount === 9) {
        doc.addPage('a4', 'landscape'); // max of 9 per page
        itemcount = 0; //  reset
      }

      doc.text(5, 10 + (itemcount * startY), `item: ${el[0]}`);
      doc.text(40, 10 + (itemcount * startY), `anotheritem: ${el[1]}`);
```